# Plane took off [from] the runway

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, prepositional-phrases

What if a phrasal verb ends in the preposition needed to connect a noun?

> The plane took off the runway. (The plane was ON the runway, and therefore preposition OFF is preferred)
>
> The plane took off from the runway.

I wanted to use 'off' not 'from', but I have never seen double 'off'.

If I am **on** a plane, I will come **off** the plane at the end.

He licked the chocolate **off** his fingers. (It was **on** his fingers)

If a plane is **on** something, it will...**off** something.

That is why I want to use 'off', but since double 'off' is incorrect, I apparently have to enjoy preposition 'from'.

Here is what I found:

> the 787 takes **off of** the runway - http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2305539

Comment: Note there is another context where you might see a similar phrase: "*the plane went **off the runway** in the thick fog*". In this case, the plane never left the ground, but instead ran off the side or the end of the runway in poor visibility.

Comment: The Daily Mail caption appears to be a mistake - I think it's meant to be "takes off *on* the runway", or something like that...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, the phrasal verb is indeed *take off*, which means:

> **[take off](http://wordnik.com/words/take%20off)** (*phrasal verb*) To leave the ground and begin flight; to ascend into the air

Second, you can use a preposition after a phrasal verb:

> *The plane took off **from** the runway.*

Third, we need to be careful about omitting the prepositions, because sometimes phrasal verbs can mean different things:

> **[take off](http://wordnik.com/words/take%20off)** (*phrasal verb*) To remove

So, without a preposition, we could say:

> *The bulldozer took off the runway, leaving nothing but brown dirt*.

Fourth, it is possible to use the same preposition found in the phrasal verb immediately after the phrasal verb; it's not "incorrect." So, if you really wanted to, you could say:

> *The plane took off off the runway*.

However, I'd recommend rewriting that, for a couple reasons:

- Although English doesn't have a rule strictly prohibiting identical consecutive words, they can still be awkward, so it's probably best to avoid them when possible
- Since we know that airplanes normally take off using runways, adding the phrase "off the runway" doesn't really add much useful information

That said, there are other examples I can think of where the last word of a phrasal verb might match the proposition immediately following it:

> - The hotel was filling up fast, but we **checked in** in time to get a room.
> - He **came around** around twenty minutes ago.
> - I **passed out** out by the meadow.
> - She had no one to **root for** for the rest of the tournament.

Like I said, though, there are often simple ways to improve such sentences – which is probably one reason you don't run across them very often. For example, you can change the prepositional phrase or the verb:

> - The hotel was filling up fast, but we checked in **early enough** to get a room.
> - The hotel was filling up fast, but we **arrived** in time to get a room.
> - He came around **about** twenty minutes ago.
> - He **wandered by** around twenty minutes ago.
> - I passed out **over near** the meadow.
> - I **fainted** out by the meadow.

Or sometimes you can simply rearrange the sentence:

> - For the rest of the tournament, she had no one to root for.

Comment: 'The plane is capable of taking off on/from grass' - acceptable?

Answer (score 12):

You are confused between 'verb' and 'phrasal verb.'

You are absolutely right that 'off' *here* means 'away'.

> I was walking *off* the road - away from the road.

But the main verb there is 'walking.' Here, the main verb, in fact [a phrasal verb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-off) is 'take off.' The 'off' is a *part* of the verb. Thus, you require the destination as well. Here, the place is 'runway.'

Hence,

> The plane took off *from* the runway.

Answer (score 7):

Intransitive **took off**:

> The plane took off.

With a locative phrase:

> The plane took off *from the runway*.

With a temporal phrase:

> The plane took off *on time*.

**off** is not a preposition there but part of the verb.  **took** alone does not mean "left the ground".

A noun can be formed from the verb:

> Refreshments were served twenty minutes after **take-off**.

P.S. There is no grammatical problem whatsoever when appending a valid prepositional phrase to any verb phrase, even if it is a phrasal verb:

> They were **carrying on** *on the dance floor*, taking off their clothes.
>
> The drunkard had passed out, but suddenly **came to** *to everyone's surprise*.
>
> My car **crapped out** *out on the interstate*.
>
> He's just **phoning it in** *in his present job*, which he hates.
>
> If we all **pitch in** *in earnest* we'll get this job done pronto.